# Accessing the resource inside load/dump

Tags: ruby, ruby-datamapper

consider the following example

```
module DataMapper
  class Property
    class CustomType < DataMapper::Property::Text

      def load(value)
        # do stuff and return formatted value 
      end
    end  
  end
end

Class A
  property :name, String
  property :value, CustomType
end
```

now when I do `A.first` or `A.first.value` the `load` method gets executed, but the calculations that I need to do inside `load` is dependent on that instance's `name` property. So how do I get the context of this instance/resource(as referred inside source code) inside the load method ?

Please let me know if the question is not clear yet !

Comment: What kind of "stuff" are you actually do inside `load`?

Comment: https://github.com/datamapper/dm-core/issues/255

Comment: Instead of trying to access the 'name' property in the load method, you might want to edit the setter for the 'name' property (in the A class), so it has a callback which does stuff to and sets the 'value' property.

Comment: Thats what I ended up doing eventually, overriding the getters & setters, but I was looking for a neater solution

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to break encapsulation.  The `name` and `value` are different properties, and thus each should be in ignorance of the other's existence, let alone value.

The correct solution is to move the "stuff" to an object which has visibility over both properties.  The two options are:

1. the `A` class (as suggested by [user1376019](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1376019/user1376019)); or
2. a complex data type, e.g. `NameAndValue < DataMapper::Property::Object`, which encapsulates both properties.

If you need to perform aggregate functions over the individual properties, the second option would not work, unless you can somehow override the complex property to have multiple fields.

In either case, *value* cannot refer to *name* without a reference to it.